# go-bindata-assetfs and gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm working on my first go web app and trying to embed files using https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs

This is my project structure:

```
project_dir
├───common
├───routers
└───templates
    ├───images
    └───css
```

generated a source file:

```
go-bindata-assetfs -pkg common -prefix "templates/" templates/css/ templates/ templates/images/
```

now I have the old routes to static files:

```
package routers
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func SetTemplatesRoutes(router *mux.Router) *mux.Router {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates"))

    router.Handle("/templates/", fs)
    router.PathPrefix("/css/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/css/",
            http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates/css")),
        ))

    router.PathPrefix("/dist/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/dist/",
            http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates/dist")),
        ))

    router.PathPrefix("/images/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/images/",
            http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates/images")),
        ))

    return router
}
```

that I'd like replace with the embedded files just to make the html templates bind the css and image files. This is my attempt:

```
    fs := http.FileServer(
        &assetfs.AssetFS{Asset: common.Asset, AssetDir: common.AssetDir, AssetInfo: common.AssetInfo})
    //
    router.Handle("/", fs)
    router.PathPrefix("/css/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/css/",
            fs,
        ))

    router.PathPrefix("/dist/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/dist/",
            fs,
        ))

    router.PathPrefix("/images/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/images/",
            fs,
        ))
```

that doesn't work.

Any suggestion to solve it?